# Create a type of nested inner object keys in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I wanted to extract the inner elements and create a new type.
For ex. to create an inner key type of:

```
    interface temp{
    a: {
        "aa":number
    }
    b:{
        "bb":number
    }
}
```

To create inner type dynamically I used:

```
type innerTemp={
    [k in keyof temp[keyof temp]]:temp[keyof temp][k]
}
```

I also tried this way:

```
 type innerTemp={
         [i in keyof T[k][k in keyof T]] : T[k][i]
    }
```

but it doesn't work the way I want. I want the inner interface to be like

```
 interface innerTemp{
     aa:number,
     bb:number,
 }
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to dynamically create inner type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the `UnionToIntersection` type:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type InnerTemp = {
    [K in keyof UnionToIntersection<Temp[keyof Temp]>]: 
      UnionToIntersection<Temp[keyof Temp]>[K]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQLYAdkG8BQyRycAXHocVQERxzWkgCuGARtJUQL6fKukEqNVqwbM2HKjx74wATywoAqiGAB7EKjUBJcNADOEBGHUgAPEoB8yALzJKACiXIIAD0ggAJvpIg5yAH5kBwBrciUAShtLADc1YE9kchAIGOgIl3cILx8HUPJQGGhkbSjY%20M8MoO0k5BS0qHxZBRRdFKh0bFsKKgBtAGlkUGQQiDk1GGQVUy1dSChDY1MzTqxe0fHJ1YBdS23yXiJpjVm9BaMTDRXMNY2JtBvdge38LiA)